# Getting the command line inside the bash script

Tags: bash

I am running a script which checks something inside the command line. If it exists, then the whole command line is ran (with all other options specified in the command). Otherwise, something else should be done.

The command is `./run -I -X -l nodes=1:ppn=4`. So, I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@" 
do
  case $i in
   -I)
      echo "Interactive job started"
      SHOULD RUN THE WHOLE COMMAND SPECIFIED IN THE COMMAND LINE
      exit
      ;;
  esac
done
#do something else
```

How can I get the whole command line inside a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command prints the entire command line inside a bash script

```
echo $0 $@
```